# Is it possible to enumerate textures with DirectX 9?

Tags: directx-9

I'm writing a plugin for an application that uses Direct3D (9.0c) as its renderer.  Not many things are exposed to my plugin, however I do have access to the IDirect3DDevice9 interface.  Using the pointer to this interface, is it possible to enumerate the textures that have been allocated?

Specifically, I'm needing to find the render targets that the application uses for a render to texture so that I can gain access to its depth buffer for use with my custom shader.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the IDirect3DDevice9 at any time, you can just use GetRenderTarget method to obtain current render target - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174404(v=vs.85).aspx . If you need an access to the depth buffer then things get complicated. If the application writes the depth to a separate texture, you can get it. If the application uses hardware depth buffer, it's rather not possible to read from it.